# Why am I getting a Type error when reversing a list using recursion

Tags: python

I am trying to write a recursion function that reverses a list.
Here is the code :

```
def recursiveReverseList(L):

    if len(L)==1:
        return L
    else:
        return [L[-1]]+recursiveReverseList(L.pop())
```

When I run this function it gives me a `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`.
Does anyone know what the problem might be ?

Comment: Is that really the error you get?

Comment: `L.pop()` returns an integer

Comment: the error is correct, since type(L) is `int` after the first pass not `list`

Comment: `L.pop()` returns the popped item, not the remaining list. Use an appropriate slice rather than `pop()`

Comment: Why are you writing a function to do this when `list.reverse()` exists? Is this homework?

Comment: This will also error when `len(L) == 0`. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Comment: I think you could change one line `return [L.pop()]+recursiveReverseList(L)`

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the built in functions?

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l.reverse()
print(l)
```

## Output:

`[5,4,3,2,1]`

---

In any case, the following does what you want:

```
def recursiveReverseList(L):
    return L if len(L) == 1 else [L[-1]]+recursiveReverseList(L[:-1])

list_ = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(recursiveReverseList(list_))
```

Note that I simply replaces `L.pop()` with `L[:-1]`

Comment: Use `len(L) <= 1` to account for an empty list

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in the return value for `.pop()`.